# Does dance of ruin hurt the caster

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, area-of-effect

I was reading the text for dance of ruin and it says it spreads outwards centred on the caster, does this mean the caster is also hit by dance of ruin?

EDIT: the spell is from the book of vile darkness

Comment: What book is Dance of Ruin from? I think one reason this question is having a hard time finding an answerer because those who have the expertise to answer it don't want to go through 30+ books looking for the exact spell-text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Quick answer:* **No, it won't.**

It is indeed from the Book of vile Darkness, a rather nasty collection of things. The descriptor of the spell:

> **[BovD: Pg. 90]** To cast this spell, the caster dances wildly and chants. After she finishes her dance, a wave of crackling energy flashes outward up to the extent of the range. All non-demon creatures within the area take 2d20 points of damage.

In the area description it says *"Spreads from the caster"*. As the wave originates from the caster, the wave does not go *through* them in a typical sense. Since it is that wave that seems to do the damage it makes sense that the caster is not damaged by the spell.

An other way to conclude this is that casters are typically not affected by their own spells unless those spells become explicit entities like a meteor swarm or a sleet storm. Compare it to the fact that a druid doesn't hurt herself using a burning hands spell.